# How to detect XSS Reflect with Perl

Tags: perl, request, xss

I created this simple script to request a URL with a JavaScript payload.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::Simple;

my $req=HTTP::Request->new(GET=>"http://example.com.br/search.asp?CI=%27%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('XSS')%3C/script%3E");
my $ua=LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->timeout(15);
my $res=$ua->request($req);
print $res->content;
```

How can I identify if there is an XSS vulnerability in this example?

Answer (score 2):

To quickly answer how it *could* work for your *particular example:*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $url = "http://example.com.br/search.asp?CI=%27%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('XSS')%3C/script%3E";

#### decode url-encoding
my $decoded_url = $url=~s/%([A-F\d]{2})/chr(hex($1))/iegr;

if ( $decoded_url=~/<script>.*<\/script>/ ) {
    print "XSS detected: $& \n";   
}
```

You'd get:

```
$ ./xssdetect.pl
XSS detected: <script>alert('XSS')</script>
```

**Caveat:** This alone is no XSS protection of real-world use. XSS is a complicated topic with lots of irregularities and special rules. I suggest reading up on XSS, for example at [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).